# about "that that" where "that" is repeated with the first being a pronoun and the second being a relative pronoun

Tags: grammar

I would like to ask if the ***that that*** expression can be used and correct. The only ***that that*** expression I can think of is the case where the first **that** is a pronoun and the second **that** is a relative pronoun.

For instance:
You and your friend Adam are in a car on the road. Your friend Adam told you a while ago that he was seeing a weird car with all people inside dressed up as clowns. And right now, you see the car is passing by.

> *The car you talked about is **that that** is going right past us.*

Surely, the first ***that*** means  **that car** and the second ***that*** is a relative pronoun.

I think this is a legitimate expression grammatically, but somehow I also feel it can be wrong as the repetition of the same word **that** might provoke confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The car you talked about is **that that** is going right past us.

is correct because:
- th3e first "that" is a pronoun, referring to car;
- the second "that" is a conjunction, withe the meaning "which":

> The car you talked about is that **which** is going right past us.

---

It can happen that the first "that" is the conjunction, as in:

> I know **that** that is the car.

- the first "that" is the conjunction;
- the second "that is the pronoun, referring to car.

---

One can use a similar repetition with other words also:

> If it did not happen **then, then** when did it happen?

- first "then" adverb, referring to time;
- second "then" conjunction, joining the clauses.

---

If you want the text to be unambiguous even for a beginner reader, then avoid these repetitions. Otherwise, use them happily - with moderation, though.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It is surprising that all of the sentences are correct. And thanks for introducing another case with the first **that** being a conjunction, which I couldn't think of.

Comment: Even though those expressions can be used and useful in colloquial use, don't they lack good quality as for written or formal language?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, since I am not a native English speaker. But, **if** I remember correctly, I saw these kinds of sentences in formal writings sometimes - so they can be used without "problem". Of course, they will be ambiguous to a beginner, but they will still be correct.

Comment: Thank you virolino for your kind response, which has helped me a lot. I think this can be pretty useful material for beginners in English. Have a great day.

Comment: You are welcome. You have a great day too.